# Trying to convert String to Integer

Tags: java, int

I am trying to convert an string into int to see the result but i am getting runtime error.

```
String string="Java";    
int see=Integer.parseInt("string");
```

and also tried for this code-

```
 String[] sstring={"Java"};
 int ssee=Interger.parseInt("sstring[0]");
```

and also tried for this code-

```
   String[] sstring={"Java"};
   int ssee=Interger.parseInt(sstring[0]);
```

Massage which I got-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For      input string: "string"
           at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
          at displayName.main(displayName.java:13)
```

Comment: Are u trying to print the ASCII numbers of the characters "Java"?

Comment: @anonymous No i was trying to see what happens if i tries to convert an string name into an integer but now i know that its impossible. How can i get the ASCII value of "Java"?

Comment: @Shantanu: There is no way whatsoever to get the contents of the variable with the name corresponding to the contents of the string in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a string containing an integer :

```
String value="10";
int x=Integer.parseInt(value);
```

If you don't pass in a valid string it will throw an exception when trying to parse, which is what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there's no integer in that string.  You have to pass it a number as a string for that to work, otherwise there's no valid value to return.

Depending on your use case, it may be perfectly ok to catch that exception and use a default value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how the `String#parseInt` is supposed to work

```
int see = Integer.parseInt("1234");
```

The string needs to represent a number.

---

Perhaps you're looking to get the ASCII value of the String?

```
String s = "Java";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an Integer Object instead of the primitive type, you can use valueOf which returns

`Integer i = Integer.valueOf("1234")`

If you are new to Java try reading it here [Difference between Integer and int.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Only numbers represented in the form of a String can be parsed using the `Integer.parseInt()` function. In other cases the `NumberFormatException` is thrown.

I would suggest Google and Wikipedia for simple things like these. They are a great source for learning and the first step towards solving simple doubts.

Hope this helped.