# Using the Integer object Java?

Tags: java

I was just reading over some Java code and asked myself why this piece of code:

```
int my_int = 100;
Long my_long = Integer.my_int.longValue();
```

would not work giving me the error, "my_int can not be resolved or is not a field" ; however this code would work:

```
Integer my_integer = new Integer(100);
Long my_long = my_integer.longValue();
```

Please explain!

Comment: What do you think `Integer.my_int.longValue()` should do and why?

Comment: `Integer.my_int.longValue();` should be `((Integer)my_int).longValue();`

Comment: int != Integer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java

Comment: You could have also used `Integer.valueof(my_int).longValue();`

Comment: Read this for a little reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer.my_int` is attempting to reference a static variable (field) named `my_int` on the class `Integer`. No such variable/field exists, which is why you get the compilation error.

The following would also work:

```
int my_int = 100;
Long my_long = Integer.valueOf(my_int).longValue();
```

However, the following is probably the better solution:

```
int my_int = 100;
Long my_long = Long.valueOf(my_int);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that `Integer` is a class and `int` is a primitive type.

Also you should try this

```
((Integer)my_int).longValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the Integer class does not have a static method named `my_int`.

You need to pass it in as a parameter to e.g. `Integer.valueOf(my_int)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Long my_long = Integer.my_int.longValue();
```

gives you an error because `my_int` is not an static field of Integer class so abviously the compiler cannot resolve it. One thing to can do to solve it is cast it to Integer and call it `longValue()` method:

```
Long my_long = ((Integer) my_int).longValue();
```

Moreover `int` is primitive type and The `Integer` class wraps a value of the primitive type int in an object.

While in `Long my_long = my_integer.longValue();`
works because you are trying to call the `longValue()` of `Integer` class and it returns the value of this `Integer` as a long which is perfectly valid.