# Why does Integer.class.isInstance(i) return true while int.class.isInstance(i) and Integer.TYPE.isInstance(i) return false?

Tags: java

What is the difference between Integer.class, int.class and Integer.TYPE? I am kind of confused between the three.

Comment: Integer.TYPE and int.class are the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Integer and int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

Whether `i` is an `int` or an `Integer`:

- `Integer.class.isInstance(i)` returns `true`
- `int.class.isInstance(i)` returns `false`
- `Integer.TYPE.isInstance(i)` returns `false`

Let's understand [`isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-).

> `public boolean isInstance(Object obj)`
>
> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class.

It takes an `Object` as an argument, not a primitive type.  Any `int` passed in will be boxed as an `Integer` so it can be passed to the method.

`Integer.class` is a class literal, and used with a reference type, that is a reference to the `Class` object for that class.

The `Integer` object that this method sees certainly is an instance of the `Integer` class, so `Integer.class.isInstance(i)` returns `true`.

However, [`int.class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) and [`Integer.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) each represent the `int` primitive type, not the `Integer` class, and an `Integer` is not an `int`, despite the fact that Java usually uses them interchangeably, due to boxing and unboxing.  This explains the two `false` outputs from `int.class.isInstance(i)` and `Integer.TYPE.isInstance(i)`.

#### Class literal history

According to the [Javadocs for `Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE), `Integer.TYPE` has been around since version 1.1.

But [class literals have also been around since 1.1](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/innerclasses/spec/innerclasses.doc9.html).

> Java APIs which require class objects as method arguments are much easier to use when the class literal syntax is available.

The class literals made it tremendously easier to use [reflection, which was also new in Java 1.1](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall97/cs461/jdkdocs/api/packages.html).

It is unclear why `Integer.TYPE` exists if `int.class` represents the `int` primitive type consistently with reference class literals.  They are equivalent and `==` yields `true` when comparing them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What is the use of int.class if we cannot get it by calling on an int variable. And i have read somewhere that Integer.TYPE defines the Class object for the wrapper classes of primitives. Then for wrapper Integer it should be Integer.TYPE. What is Integer.class then?

Comment: @Birendra - First, note that `int.class == Integer.TYPE`. They are the same object. Second, `int.class` (or `Integer.TYPE`) is useful when dealing with reflection. Several methods of `Class` expect as arguments the `Class` objects representing the types of the arguments to constructors or methods. When the argument is an `int`, then `int.class` (or `Integer.TYPE`) is used to represent that argument. Finally, `Integer.class` represents the class of objects that are instances of `Integer` (not primitive `int` values).

Comment: maybe they couldn't make up their mind. `int.class` does look odd; not to mention `void.class`

Comment: @Ted Hopp I was reading "Thinking in Java" where the author said that int.class is for the primitive type and Integer.TYPE is for the primitive wrapper type.

Comment: @Birendra - I'm not sure why the author would say that. Perhaps he was mislead by the type of `Integer.TYPE` being `Class<Integer>`. The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) clearly say that `Integer.TYPE` is _"The `Class` instance representing the primitive type `int`."_. It is easy enough to write a program to test this: `int.class == Integer.TYPE` will be `true`; `i.getClass() == Integer.class` will be `true` for any `Integer` variable `i`; `Integer.class == Integer.TYPE` will be `false`. Also, `Integer.TYPE.isPrimitive()` will return `true`.

Comment: @Ted Hopp This is the reason i was confused in the first place. That is why i put this question in the first place. Thanks any way for helping me understand.