# How to get parameter's value in a return method from another method?

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing, return-value

My `int dice` in `MovePath()` method needs to get the value of `int step` in `GetRollDice()` method.

I'm using Java.

How should I do that?

```
public static int getRollDice(){
   int[] diceStep= {-2,-1,1,2,3};            
   int randomStep = new Random().nextInt(diceStep.length); 
   int step = diceStep[randomStep];
   return step;
}

public static int MovePath(Integer dice,Integer path){
  // int dice = step value from GetRollDice      
  //Get Initial Path
  //Next path = roll dice value + initial path


    return path;

}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the programming language your are using ? If so, if think it is some Java, am I right ?

Comment: @dkg i'm so sorry. Yes it is java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to call your method, no need to redeclare `dice` :

```
public static int MovePath(Integer dice,Integer path){
    dice = getRollDice();     
    //Get Initial Path
    //Next path = roll dice value + initial path

    return path;
}
```

---

Keep in mind that everything in Java is a reference to an `Object`... everything but primitive types like `int`, `short`, etc...

See [What is the difference between Integer and int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java) for more information about this.