# What is the use of creating an integer object in java?

Tags: java, object, integer

I created an integer object as well as a primitive int variable!
I gave the same value to both.
I performed math operations on both to compare if there is any difference.I couldn't find any difference.

So my question is -what is the advantage of using integer object instead of primitive int datatype?

Is there any specific or different kind of operation that can be performed on integer object?

What is the use of creating one?

I searched on google but I was redirected to some other questions related to integer in stackoverflow!
I couldn't find any related question.
Please help me!

Comment: [read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I got it now!

Comment: For details: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/

Comment: this is x vs y question, so you should google same way https://www.google.de/search?q=int+vs+integer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=W31hVurVPJONapHCmcAC

Comment: @Mathews Of course C and C++ flags were completely needed here.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as C++ and C when it is clearly a Java question?

Comment: They have similar kind of mechanism and syntax.
Java is basically based on c syntax.So I though even c experts could help!

Comment: with the same logic you could add the database tag, because also a databasse expert might know the answer. Please dont spam tags.