# Check if key is in map - one way works and the other doesn't

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to check whether a key is in a map(Java) and am a bit confused about why one of my solutions works and the other doesn't.

In particular: when I compare `myMap.get(s)` directly to `null` it works but when I first save `myMap.get(s)` to a variable (`number`) and then compare to `null` it throws a `The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null` error.

Code that works:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class test1{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        // Create a map
        Map<String, Integer> myMap; 
        myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // Make an entry in the map
        String key = "hello";
        int value = 5;
        myMap.put(key, value);


        String s = "hi";

        if (myMap.get(s) != null)
        {
            int number = myMap.get(s);
            System.out.printf("%s\n", number);
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Not in dict");
        }
    }
}
```

Code that does not work:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class test2{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        // Create a map
        Map<String, Integer> myMap; 
        myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // Make an entry in the map
        String key = "hello";
        int value = 5;
        myMap.put(key, value);


        String s = "hi";
        int number = myMap.get(s);
        if (number != null)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s\n", number);
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Not in dict");
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how I am supposed to understand this, because to me `myMap.get(s)` is also just an int?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `int` != `Integer`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)
Null can not be assigned to a primitive type

Comment: You know there's a method `Map.containsKey()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int` can never be `null`, but an `Integer` can.

`myMap.get(s)` returns an `Integer`, which can be `null`.

```
int number = myMap.get(s);
```

would throw a `NullPointerException` if `myMap.get(s)` returns `null`.

If you want to safely assign the value to a variable, use an `Integer` variable:

```
Integer number = myMap.get(s);
if (number != null) {
    System.out.printf("%s\n", number);
} else {
    System.out.println("Not in dict");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I would only like to add this link to a question about the difference between `int` and `Integer`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`number` is of **primitive type** `int` and therefore cannot be `null`.
If you instead write `Integer number = myMap.get(s);`, your `null`-check would work.

But to check if a key is present, you should use `containsKey(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you are storing the value on a "int" varible, that is a primivitive and never can be null. Change it to "Integer" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

`int number = myMap.get(s);` returns an `Integer` and it can be `null`. Therefore when it is `null`, the primitive `int` cannot hold that value and will cause an exception. Either use `Integer` to store the value, or use `contains()` to check before accessing.