# Clarification of remove for Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

So ArrayList in JAVA has 2 remove function 1 return the oldvalue and the other return boolean.

```
remove(Object) return boolean
remove(index) return oldvalue
```

now if both the object also integer then how JAVA differentiate

Ex:- in the code     `arr.remove(j);`

Code

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 2; i < 239697453; i++) {
    arr.add(i);
}
int a = arr.size();
for (int i = 2; i < a; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 j < a; j++) {
        if (arr.get(j) % i == 0) {
            arr.remove(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `j` isn't an `Integer`, it's an `int`.

Comment: distinction is based on primitive int which means its an index while wrapper is an object and hence remove is actual removal of an object of present.

Answer (score 6):

Java firstly will choose the most suitable version of method - because

```
remove(int i)
```

is fitting better than

```
remove(Integer i) // autoboxing necessary
```

it will call the *index* version of `remove` method

To force Java to use *item* version you can create `Integer` object using `Integer.valueOf()` and pass it to the `remove` method

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(myInt))
```

See related page, [*What is the difference between Integer and int in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8660691/642706)