# How to compare a get function of HashMap with null value?

Tags: java

I am stuck on a problem, I am not sure how to do it,

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
            {
                int value = hmap2.get(arr1[i]);
                if ( value != 0 || value != null )
                {
                    System.out.print(arr1[i]+" ");
                    hmap2.put(arr1[i], --value);
                }
            }
```

In this code snippet, the variable `value` will have a null value when `arr1[i]` doesn't exist in the map. So when this happens I don't want to print the `arr[i]` value. How can I do it because it is throwing error can't compare arguments? what am I doing wrong?

I want to make sure that when there is no mapping for `arr1[i]` in the map, I should skip it and not print it.

Comment: Is `arr` an int array or an Integer array?

Comment: Always include declarations in code. It is more readable.

Comment: See `containsKey` for a more expressive solution as in: `if (hmap2.containsKey(arr1[i]))`... .  Note that a hashmap can contain an key=>null mapping but you seem to be interested in whether the key exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**int** can't be `null`, but **Integer** can.
This will work for you:

```java
Integer value = hmap2.get(arr1[i]);
```

In Java, **int** is a primitive type and it is not considered an object. Only objects can have a null value. The class **Integer** represents an int value, but it can hold a null value. 
This behavior is different from some more purely object oriented languages like Ruby, where even "primitive" things like ints are considered objects.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the not null check. The primitive int can’t be null and thus it’s always true

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved if you use `Integer` instead of `int`

Change your code to `Integer value = hmap2.get(arr[i]);` and now value can hold null value.

Refer the difference between Integer and int

[Difference between int and Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java)