# How many objects created by JVM

Tags: java, jvm

If we use

`Boolean boolean = new Boolean(true);`

and

`Integer integer = new Integer(10);`

then how many objects are created and where do they reside?

Comment: 2 Objects get created they reside in the addresses pointed to by `boolean` and `integer`

Comment: *Trick question:* **1 and 0.** The first line creates 1 object, the second line doesn't run, because it doesn't compile, so it cannot create anything. *Objects* are always created on the heap.

Comment: Sorry @Andreas. I'll edit the question.

Comment: So you mean there is not difference between using a wrapper class to create a primitive datatype and directly assigning value?

Comment: Like new Integer(20) is same as int x = 20?

Comment: There is a difference: see the link in my answer

Comment: Of course there is a difference. `Integer integer = new Integer(10)` create a new object instances on the heap and stores the reference to it in the `integer` *reference* variable. `int x = 20` doesn't create any object instances but simply stores the value 20 in the `x` *primitive* variable.

Comment: Also note that there is a cache for `Integer` in the range of -128 to 127 and for `Boolean`. Therefore, auto-boxing and `valueOf(...)` won't necessarily create new object instances but just refer to already existing ones.

Comment: @Matt - However, the OP is not using auto-boxing.  When an instance is created using `new`, you will always get a new one.  At least, that is true for all versions of Java so far released.

Comment: @StephenC - Yes, you will always get a new instance by using the constructor and the OP is not using auto-boxing in the question. But OP dives deeper in the comments and generally asked about wrapper-classes and assignment. Additionally,  @Andreas mentioned the primitive case (`int x = 20`). In this context, IMHO, my comment adds another important aspect to the discussion since `Integer x = 20` behaves differently than `Integer x = 2000`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you would end up with 1 instance of `Integer` which is referred to by `integer` and 1 instance of `Boolean` which is referred to by `boolean`. The instances will be created on the heap.

See: [int vs Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java)

Comment: Object instances don't have names, and don't reside on the stack, they reside on the heap. The *reference value* that is referring to the instance has a name and resides on the stack or heap, depending on where that code is located.

Comment: Reformulated my answer a bit

Answer (score 1):

> How many objects are created and where do they reside?

- Two objects created.  Each `new` will create a new object.
- All Java objects reside in the heap ... so they reside in the heap.

In the other hand, if you use `int` instead of `Integer` and `boolean` instead of `Boolean` then:

- No objects are created.
- The values `true` and `10` will be *in* the variables ... and will therefore reside wherever the variables reside.  That will depend on what *kind* of variables they are.

Finally, consider this version:

```
Boolean boolean = true
Integer integer = 10;
```

The difference between this and your original version is that two values are produced by auto-boxing.  This will EITHER create new objects OR reuse objects that have been created before, and have been cached.  (It depends on the type, the JVM implementation, and the in some cases the cache size configured by JVM options.)

So the answers will be:

- Zero, one or two objects will be created, depending on the above factors.
- The objects will be in the heap (as before).

Note: auto-boxing obtains the objects by calling the wrapper classes `valueOf` method.  You can call it explicitly in your own code as an alternative to autoboxing.  It is better to do this than to use `new`.

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(10);      // bad - generates an unnecessary object
Integer i2 = 10;                   // good - auto-boxing uses (may use) cached object
Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf(10);  // equivalent to auto-boxing
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Objects will be created .. one boolean object and one integer object residing in the heap memory.